# 3D plotting using scatter3 in Matlab with a colormap; the colorbar scaling is not correct

Tags: matlab, plot

This should be simple, but I'm having trouble getting the scaling of a custom color map to match the range of values that I'm plotting. I don't quite understand how to get the range on the colorbar to match the range of the Z-dimension data. Here's a simple example that I'm trying to get working:

```
maxval = 5;
num = 10;
X = linspace(0,maxval,num);
Y = linspace(0,maxval,num);
Z = linspace(0,maxval,num);
cMap = interp1([0;1],[1 .5 0; .5 1 0],linspace(0,1,num));
scatter3(X,Y,Z,50,cMap,'Filled');
view(-75,20);
colormap(cMap)
colorbar
```

Which gives this:

[image: Example plot]

I want the top value in the colorbar to be 5 in this example.  I've tried modifying the [0;1] in the interp1 function, but I can't seem to get the correct settings.

I'm using version 2017a, if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 5th input in `scatter3` can represent a completely independent axis of data. If you want the color to match the Z axis data, then you need to pass it in twice.

The custom colormap (which can be a different size than the data) in interpolated to this 5th input to make the display.

Pragmatically, I think you want to make the following change to your code:

```
maxval = 5;
num = 10;
X = linspace(0,maxval,num);
Y = linspace(0,maxval,num);
Z = linspace(0,maxval,num);
cMap = interp1([0;1],[1 .5 0; .5 1 0],linspace(0,1,num));
scatter3(X,Y,Z,50,Z,'Filled');   % <-- note change here
view(-75,20);
colormap(cMap)
colorbar
```

Comment: Did you implement a change on that line?  It looks the same as my original.

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy/paste error. Fixed now.